# select most popular items

Tags: mysql, select

I have the following query:

```
SELECT
    l.id,
    l.name,
    l.url,
    c.name,
    COUNT(cc.id) AS popularity
FROM
    links AS l,
    categories AS c,
    clicks AS cc
WHERE
    l.category_id = c.id
AND
    l.id = cc.link_id
AND
    l.active = 1
ORDER BY
    popularity DESC
LIMIT 
    10
```

As you can see, I have 3 tables: links, categories and clicks. In 'clicks' I saved a record every time a number is clicked. I want to select the 10 most popular links, but I only get the last record with all the clicks combined.

What's wrong with my query?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

seems you need group by

```
SELECT
    l.id,
    l.name,
    l.url,
    c.name,
    COUNT(*) AS popularity
FROM
    links AS l, 
    categories AS c,
    clicks AS cc
WHERE  l.category_id = c.id
AND    l.id = cc.link_id
AND    l.active = 1
GROUP BY l.id, c.name
ORDER BY popularity DESC LIMIT 10
```